# Uploading images on server using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I've uploaded my website to 000webhost server. there is a problem of images it don't show up when I upload them. it was working fine while I'm on localhost
I moved my public folder to public_html folder on the server but I can't create a symlink on the server I tried this line but it didn't work

[image]

symlink('/agroam/agroam/storage/app/public', '/agroam/public_html/storage');

Can anyone tell me why? or give me another way to make it works

Comment: What about permissions ? And also you can see in log.

Comment: Which permissions? I'm new in laravel

Comment: Have you checked in storage/app/public folder? That's usually where the files are stored.

Comment: Images stored fine in storage/app/public folder the problem is how to access this folder from public_html folder

Answer (score 1):

Using 000web free hosting symlink is disabled that is why the line doesn't work. You have to upgrade to premium version so you can have SSH access to your account.